# fetching value with the submit button in HTML?

Tags: php, html, css

If the submit button is pressed in HTML I need to send some value with it.  How can I do it?

```
<input type="submit" name="ask" class="tbutton" value="ask" />

if(isset($_POST['ask'])){
    // i need to fetch some value that is passed with submit button }
```

Comment: Use a `<input type='hidden' value="..." />`

Comment: You *are* passing a value. That's what the value attribute does.

Comment: i want to pass some hidden integer value with the submit button but i am not getting how to send it @EatPeanutButter

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to fetch value of some input right?

may be this will help

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" name="myText" />
 <input type="submit" name="ask" class="tbutton" value="ask" />
</form>

<?php
   if(isset($_POST['ask'])){
      echo($_POST['myText']);
   }
?>
```

Comment: This indeed answers the question, although I personally find it more elegant to just check if `myText` is set, so that users that submit the form by pressing the return key also get served.

Comment: @Rick Pressing the return key acts like clicking the submit button, so `$_POST['ask']` will be set. Maybe you're thinking of AJAX form submission, which doesn't include buttons.

Comment: @Barmar Just tried, for me it doesn't... refer to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/RickWieman/d56fea2a5ee44b24a5d7f82d8cb48e16), it only lists the submit button if I explicitly click on it... Just pressing the return key omits the `InputSubmit` entry.

Comment: @Rick When I try it, it prints `Array ( [InputText] => text [InputSubmit] => Submit Button )`. I tried both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @Barmar Hmm, then it might be browser dependent... On Safari 9.1 (Mac OS X), it doesn't, but on Chrome 50 (Mac OS X) (now that you mention it), it does.

Comment: I'm still on Snow Leopard, Safari 5.1 is like Chrome.

Comment: @Rick https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission says _If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly ..., then doing so for a form whose default button has a defined activation behavior must cause the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on that default button._ I haven't examined the referred sections carefully, but I think it means it's supposed to emulate clicking on the default button.

Comment: @Rick Just tried Safari 9.0 on BrowserStack, it sends the submit button.

Comment: @Barmar I'm flabbergasted. Safari now also submits the button. Never mind then, thanks for pointing that out.